# Link To Already Defined Path In Menu Using hook_menu()

Tags: 7, routes

I'm sure this is an obvious answer but I seem to be missing something important.

How can I add a link to a menu **using hook_menu()** to an already defined path?

I'm trying to add a direct link to a node/add page that already exists.

I need to use hook_menu() instead of the control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can best use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7), which should be used when "Additional items may be added, or existing items altered."

In *custom_node_add.module* :

```
function custom_node_add_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (aray_key_exists) { //some sanity checking;
    $items['node/add']['page callback'] = 'custom_node_add_page'
  }
}

function custom_node_add_page() {
  return t("Hello World! This is content on my node/add page");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really should have spent more time searching.  The following works beautifully in `hook_menu();`

```
$items['customeurltocreate/nodetype'] = array(
        'title' => 'Create Node Type',
        'page callback' => '_menu_create_node_type',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

function _menu_create_node_type() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    return node_add('node_type');
}
```

Comment: This only works if your module is called after that other module; which is very flakey. You should either force your module to be ran after that other by changing the weight in the system table. Or use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)